# Internet application or window application?

Tags: browser, window

I should develop a online search application which connects to an external database in a different server. This application can be a web application one (running on a Internet browsers basically) or a normal standard window application (with its own GUI). Does one of the two approaches have more benefits of the other? If so, which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are advantages and drawbacks with each solution, of course ; here are a couple of thoughts :

- Web applications are easy to update : you have control over the server, and you deploy whenever you want
- Web applications pretty much garantee that all users are using the same version of your application : the current one *(i.e. no-one is running an old, non-updated version)*
- Desktop application can use more memrory and CPU : the limit is on the user's computer *(and there is one computer per user)*, and not on the server *(shared by several users)*
- Desktop applications only work on systems you developped them for *(i.e. windows/Linux/Mac 32/64 bits)*

In your case, if most of the work is done by the external database, I suppose the web/desktop application would only be a front-end that sends queries and display data in return ?

If so, you probably don't need much power on the application-side : almost everything will be on the database side, which is necessarily shared amongst users.

In such a case, I would probably go for a web-application : easier to update, works on all platforms, doesn't require much server-power.

*(Disclaimer : I am a web-developper -- so might be a bit biased ^^ )*

Comment: The point about desktop application can use more Memory and CPU, is totally up to the programmer and how he creates the software. Depends what he includes, but as a rule of thumb I would argue the opposite, as you don't have the overhead of the browser.

Comment: What I actually meant is that on a desktop computer with 2 GB of RAM, if an application uses 100MB, it's not that bad ;;; on a server with 4GB RAM and 50 users, if each user requires 100MB of RAM, your server will die.

Answer (score 0):

Both have advantages and disadvantages.

But a online search application I would strongly suggest a web application due to the following reasons:

- Can be accessed from anywhere in the world (either directly or through VPN) through a web browser( which is installed almost on every single computer out there)
- Does not need any permissions from the users side, e.g. administrative permissions/networking access. A web browser will have these by default and run over HTTP which is allowed through most firewalls.
- Can be easily updated, update the website and the changes will be made next time t he user goes on the website, with a desktop application you have to script an update feature, or tell user to download new version.
- Works on all platforms, no need to worry about cross-platform coding.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Pascal MARTIN. To add a couple of things:
- Desktop apps could perform better as far as UI goes (although with RIA platforms -GWT, Silverlight, Flex- this might not be so true anymore), or allow you to use more complex widgets which might be harder to implement in a web app.